# Log in function in OpenCart

Tags: php, authentication, opencart

I am building a web export to OpenCart.  I already have an export to Magento. the log in functie for Magento is this:

```
function login($usr,$pwd, $return_session = false) {

    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'));

    // supply username
    $user = Mage::getModel('admin/user'); // user your admin username

    if(!$user->authenticate($usr, $pwd)){
        $this->errors[] = "Username or password is incorrect.";
    }

    if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->useSecretKey()) {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->renewSecretUrls();
    }

    $session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
    $session->setIsFirstVisit(true);
    $session->setUser($user);
    $session->setAcl(Mage::getResourceModel('admin/acl')->loadAcl());
    Mage::dispatchEvent('admin_session_user_login_success',array('user'=>$user));

    if (!count($this->errors)) {
        $loggedin = true;
        Mage::init();
        Mage::app("default")->setCurrentStore( Mage_Core_Model_App :: ADMIN_STORE_ID );
        $this->sess_id = $session->getEncryptedSessionId();
    } else{
        //print_r($this->errors);
        $loggedin = false;
    }
    //Returns boolean whether login data is correct or not
    if ($return_session) {
        return $session;
    }
    return $loggedin;
}
```

I hope there is someone who knows how to do this in OpenCart. If you don't know it, but you know which functions i need to use, then i also would like to hear it.

I hope there is someone who can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Opencart version 2.3:

This controller file is responsible for customer login form:

```
catalog/controller/account/login.php
```

And this file, has `login`, `logout` and some more functions for customer:

```
system/library/cart/customer.php
```

Answer (score 0):

There is in "system/library" a file named "account.php", this contains the login function for the accounts. To use this in controllers you can use the "$this->account" library.

**Example**

```
if($this->account->login('username', 'password'))
  echo 'Logged in!';'
else
  echo 'Failed!'
```